# Embedding a global variable in standalone Matlab executable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I'm using [mcc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/ml_code/mcc.html) to compile my Matlab function(s) into a standalone executable for my target platform. I'd like to be able to reference a global variable that was written into the executable at build time, when running the executable.

For example

1. At build time, I extract the git commit hash of the repository, `commitHash`
2. `commitHash` somehow becomes a global variable inside my executable
3. Every output of my executable (a file) is tagged with `commitHash`

The challenge here is that the commit hash is only known at build time and the standalone executable will no longer be in a repository when it's running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a MATLAB function that uses `system` to call the `git` program and queries the commit ID, and then creates a simple M-file function (`commitHash.m`) that returns this value, it just writes out the M-file to disk.

This generated function is used in your code where you want to output your commit ID. The `mcc` program will include this function in the stand-alone executable's bundle.

You could write a build script, which simply calls your the function that generates the `commitHash.m` M-file, and then calls `mcc`. This ensures that the `commitHash.m` file is updated every time you build your bundle.

---

The M-file generated with the commit ID would be something like this:

```matlab
function id = commitHash
id = '0123456789abcdef';
```

This is the standard way of creating a constant in MATLAB. In your program you could use it this way:

```matlab
fprintf('My program, commit ID: %s\n', commitHash);
```

The benefit of doing it this way, and not embed the ID in your actual program, is that this way you don't modify code that is in your repository -- committing the change would change the commit ID, which would be weird.

Add the `commitHash.m` file to your `.gitignore` file to prevent it from being committed.